# How does skipping taxi rides work?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Single player.

Sometimes when I start a taxi journey I get the option to skip. Sometimes I don't.

Any character, any length of journey. Before I owned the cab company and after. All characters have millions in cash.

Is it just broken?

Comment: Guessing here, but it's quite possibly a trick to hide load times. So if the area you're skipping to isn't loaded, you can't skip

Comment: Sounds plausible, however I'm sure I've skipped from the city to the north coast.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out ... it only seems to be offered as an option if you're using an external camera view in cars. I always drive with the in-car camera, so when I get in a taxi it's the back seat view. Bizarre. Thanks for documenting that, R* ...

Comment: In other words, to help other viewers of this question, you need to be looking at the taxi in an external vehicle camera view before the skip option becomes available. Hit the 'back' button on the 360 controller.